# QR code ruining hash link with special character encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, special-characters, qr-code

Using a jquery plugin called jquery.qrcode and a qrcode scanner called AT&TCodeScanner on an iPad, my hash links get their special characters encoded into something else, therefore ruining the hash. I wasn't sure if this was a problem with the nature of QR codes itself, so I posted it here. In the event it isn't, I am willing to delete this and move it to Super User.

The following code successfully generates a QR code. However, when I scan it on AT&TCodeScanner with an iPad, all the special characters after the hash tag get the equivalent of encodeURIComponent() done to them ("#" => "%23", "=" => "%3D, etc), messing up the hash links. See the bottom of the page for the actually scanned link.

```
<div class="qr-3 qr-code"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

      $(".qr-3").qrcode({
        render: 'image',
        size: 86,
        fill: '#000',
        text: "http://www.google.com/search?tbm=shop&gws_rd=ssl#tbs=vw:l,mr:1,local_avail:1,seller:1311674%7C8740%7C1192406%7C9119074%7C3136905&q=lre3083st"
      });
});
</script>
```

http://www.google.com/search?tbm=shop&gws_rd=ssl%23tbs%3Dvw%3Al%2Cmr%3A1%2Clocal_avail%3A1%2Cseller%3A1311674%257C8740%257C1192406%257C9119074%257C3136905%26q%3Dlre3083st

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried the same stuff and it seems to be working just fine. Here is the code I used:

```
$('#qrcodeholder').qrcode({
        text    : "http://www.google.com/search?tbm=shop&gws_rd=ssl#tbs=vw:l,mr:1,local_avail:1,seller:1311674%7C8740%7C1192406%7C9119074%7C3136905&q=lre3083st",
        render  : "canvas",  // 'canvas' or 'table'. Default value is 'canvas'
        background : "#ffffff",
        foreground : "#000000",
        width : 150,
        height: 150
    });


});
```

The html for the same was :

```
<div id="qrcodeholder"> </div>
```

When I scan, I get the same value, however I tried using a different QR Code scanner named "Barcode scanner".

I'm using `jquery.qrcode.js`, [Generate QR Code using jQuery](http://www.moreonfew.com/generate-qr-code-using-jquery/) has more explanation to this. However one prominent thing I noticed is that you might want to change the `render:"image"` to `render:"canvas"` .

Comment: Thanks, it was totally the QR code app I was using. Switched it to something else and didn't run into any problems.